# PHP file upload failure for large files

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, upload

Using a simple php script, when I try to upload files larger than 1MB it fails by giving this undescriptive error:

> General upload failure.

Nginx error log does not show any evidence.

I have set in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M 
post_max_size = 200M 
memory_limit = 128M
```

and in nginx.conf I have:

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

The odd thing is that the script used to work well on the same server (before Debian server uprade) and already works well on another server with the very same nginx and php configs. So I'm really out of ideas so appreciate youre help.

Comment: Have you checked that the right php.ini file will be used (there are different file for different purposes cli, apache2, fpm)? Additionally check if the Nginx setting is in the correct context (can be http, server or location).

Comment: Well, the php.ini is for php5/fpm which is relevant. And nginx' client_max_body_size is in the context of http in nginx.conf